# sql script left outer join issue

Tags: outer-join

```
**Table 1**
Tbcode    description    Amount
2        debtors         40000
3        creditors       50000
4        share_capital   10000
5        reserve         20000
**Table 2**
Tbcode    description    Amount
1          debtors        3000
2          creditors      7000
3          share_capital    0
4          reserve        3000
4          reserve        2000
2          creditors        300
3          share_capital  3000
4          reserve        3000
1          debtors        2000
```

I have to put a left outer join on `table 1`

In my output `table I` need all the columns of `table 1` and the sum of `amount` column group by `TB code`.

I have written the following script:

```
select openingtb.TBCODE,openingtb.DESCRIPTION,openingtb.AMOUNT,count(journals.AMOUNT)
from openingtb
left outer join journals
on openingtb.tbcode = journals.TBCODE
group by journals.TBCODE.TBCODE
;
```

Can someone guide me as to whats wrong with the code and what could be the correct code to get the required output

Comment: [mcve], please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it you use aggregate function, then you should group all non-aggregate fields used in select clause...

```
SELECT openingtb.TBCODE, openingtb.DESCRIPTION, openingtb.AMOUNT
, Count(journals.AMOUNT)
FROM openingtb
LEFT JOIN journals
ON openingtb.tbcode = journals.TBCODE
GROUP BY openingtb.TBCODE, openingtb.DESCRIPTION, openingtb.AMOUNT
;
```

Comment: Can you also tell me if the output table can be stored as a new table in the database?

Comment: `create table as (select... )`